# Cannot connect to Wordpress docker container in localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I changed the docker-compose.yaml file to the following:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  MySQL:
    container_name: MySQL
    image: mysql:8.0.19
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pskPSK258##
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pskPSK258##
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - MySQL
    container_name: WordPresss
    image: wordpress:5.4.0-php7.4-fpm-alpine
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - wordpress-volume:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: MySQL:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: tbl
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: pskPSK258##

volumes:
  mysql-volume:
    name: mysql-volume
    driver: local
  wordpress-volume:
    name: wordpress-volume
    driver: local
```

I still have the same problem as before, but when I use wordpress: 5.4.0-php7.4 without Alpine, I have no problem connecting. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Not sure what issue you were having 'before'. Are you sure the two containers use the same port? Are you sure you are connecting to the right port on localhost?

Comment: You have no `Networks:` section.